# Colorbox Overwrite close actions

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have an ajax colorbox script where if a success submit is done, only then, on esc, close or click outside to execute window.location.reload();

The problem is that my function is not executed. I think first is closing the colorbox so there is nothing to execute anymore. What can I do to execute my function before colorbox functions.

This is the code inside the modal: http://jsfiddle.net/33BbG/

Thank you

Comment: Post an example that illustrates what is going wrong.

Comment: Nothing it's going on, just a colorbox ajax modal with a function inside that has to execute a function on close, esc or outside click before colorbox exectutes his own functions (closing the colorbox). This has to happen only in that modal another function is true. That is why I can't do this from the colorbox execution at first!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to override the automatic closing feature of the plugin with some of your own code.

For example, redefining the method **$.colorbox.close()** will allow you to trap the default exit conditions and block them until your application logic has completed as you need it to.  Then you can allow the closing of the colorbox.

This FAQ from the ColorBox website should get you started...

- http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq#faq-close

Regards, Kevin M.

Answer (score 0):

You you run it with opened debug you will see that you missed `'` on the following line:
`$(a.close, a.btn-close, .cboxOverlay').live('click', function(e){`